# What does this class definition mean in C#?

Tags: c#, class, syntax

I saw a class defined like this:

```
public class TheAppointments : JavaScriptConverter
{
```

What does this mean? I'm kinda new to C#.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are inheriting from the JavaScriptConverter class.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson08.aspx

Comment: It can also mean that TheAppointments class implements the JavaScriptConverer interface but who in their right minds would create an interface that doesn't start with a capitalized "I". Those cowboy coders and their lack of standards!

Comment: ok; I get it. What's the difference between implementing an interface and inheriting from a class. In this context, is it an interface or a class inheritance?

Comment: No way to tell from the example. An interface defines a set of methods and parameters with no code in the methods. A class of course, can contain data, and will have code in the methods. The purpose of an interface is to standardize a set of methods that any implementing class will have to contain. An interface can never be instantiated by itself. It's not a class -- more a template used to force classes to offer certain services.

Comment: 99% of the time (and with good standards), an interface will be titled starting with a capital "I". I'm going under the assumption (and a pretty safe one), that this is not one because of that.

Answer (score 3):

The `:` notation is used to signify that the class `TheAppointments` inherits from the class `JavaScriptConverter`. Check out [Wikipedia's explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) for some background info about inheritance in object oriented programming.

Answer (score 2):

That means the class TheAppointments inherits from JavaScriptConverter

Answer (score 2):

The overall meaning is you are defining a new class that is defined (a.k.a a subclass of) JavaScriptConverter.

The public part means that the class is visible to everything, in that anything can reference that class and create it if it has a public constrcutor.

The class part, well means it is a class. Other syntax that goes here could include interface and enum.